# How to contact a person knowing their public IP address?

Tags: router, ip, user

I've inadvertently ended up in someone else's router admin.

I've got full control.

I want to let the user know that if this access should fall into the wrong hands he may find some unforeseen issues.

How can I track the IP to a person's email address. I have public IP and the name of the computers on the network.

Comment: "How can I track the IP to a person's email address." - You can't.  The ip address and a name of a computer alone, is not enough to identify somebody.

Comment: Probably the best you can do is contact their ISP and ask them to inform their customer.

Comment: Adding to other comments, you can use [this](http://ipaddress.com/ip-lookup/) to search for some useful details about that IP.

Comment: @PrashantKumar96 - Its only as accurate as the information supplied.  It also won't identified the user who is assigned that ip address.  Your average joe blow do not own IPv4 addresses, they might be assigned a static ip address, but they are not owned by that single individual.

Comment: @Ramhound I understand that. That's why I wrote _some details about that IP_ which can be used, like location or ISP as David mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having control of the router is just the same as controlling the other guy's
local network, which means that you could invite yourself into his network.
If he is as clueless as it seems, his network is called WORKGROUP and his PC
is quite visible on it. Even his phone might be visible on it.

This gives you many hacking opportunities, but all of them are probably illegal.
In many countries, just going into his router is called hacking.

Once you are on his network and can see his computer,
then depending on your and his Windows versions, you might be able to send him
a message using either the commands of
[msg](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771903%28WS.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
or
[net send](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490710.aspx).
A third option that uses PowerShell is
[this script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/A-net-messenger-script-for-810f8331).

If this works, you had better spend a lot of thought on wording a message that
will not send the guy screaming to his ISP or the police,
causing you lots of trouble.

Imagine if the guy's bank account gets hacked, and if the police find traces
of your having visited his router. Some routers keep logs.
Frankly, my best advice would be to forget the whole thing and to stay away from his router.